# making zend tutorial getting error from existing file

Tags: php, zend-framework3

[image]

THis is my directory in making a zend framework album module

But I am getting this

> [Thu Dec 21 14:45:23.609465 2017] [:error] [pid 15352] [client 127.0.0.1:56476] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/Profile/module/Album/config/module.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/Profile/module/Album/Module.php on line 32
>   [Thu Dec 21 14:45:23.609500 2017] [:error] [pid 15352] [client 127.0.0.1:56476] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/Profile/module/Album/config/module.config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/Profile/module/Album/Module.php on line 32

Now I am confused why I am getting the error when I can see that the file exist in my folder.

I followed the instruction carefully from the docs and copied all the codes

I am wondering why I am getting this error and where I went wrong?

FYI:

Instead of naming zf2tutorial I named mine Profile just to clarify

Comment: Check the file permissions of the folders and the file, it may be that it can't read the file.

Comment: Seems like there are mistakes in config files location. You Module.php and autoload_classmap.php should be next to the `src/` folder. Might not resolve your issue though, it's the convention adopted by Zend. Following psr-7 new standard you can move all the content in `src/Album` to the `src/` folder and remove the `src/Album`